# Sumar todas las categorías con SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

Tengo los siguientes modelos

```py
class Transactions(db.Model, BaseModelMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    amount = db.Column(db.Double)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories_transactions.id'), nullable=False)
    category = db.relationship('CategoriesTransactions',  backref = 'transactions', uselist=False)

class CategoriesTransactions(db.Model, BaseModelMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'categories_transactions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)


    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Los siguientes datos guardados en *Transactions* y en *CategoriesTransactions*

*TRANSACTIONS*

| ID | description | amount | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hojas | 600.00 | 1 |

*CATEGORIES TRANSACTIONS*

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Oficina y Papeleria |
| 2 | Nomina |
| 3 | Otros |

Y la siguiente consulta

```py
 db.session.query(
   func.sum(Transactions.amount).label('total'),
   CategoriesTransactions.name.label('categoryName'),
 ).join(
    CategoriesTransactions,
    CategoriesTransactions.id == Transactions.category_id,
    isouter=True
).group_by(Transactions.category_id).all()
```

La cual me regresa los siguientes datos

```
600.0, 'Papeleria y oficina'
```

Pero me gustaría obtener lo siguiente

```
600.0, 'Papeleria y oficina'
0, 'Nomina'
0, 'Otros'
```

¿Qué necesito en mi consulta para obtener las otras categorías a pesar de que no tengan un registro en la tabla de Transactions?

Comment: El  problema no es mysql ni de sql.. es de flask.. porque en sql se soluciona con un left join...

Comment: Si bien tenés puesto `isouter=True` para el LEFT JOIN: ¿intentaste cambiar `CategoriesTransactions.id == Transactions.category_id` por `Transactions.category_id == CategoriesTransactions.id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.session.query(
    func.sum(Transactions.amount).label('total'),
    CategoriesTransactions.name.label('categoryName'),
).join(
    Transactions,
    CategoriesTransactions.id == Transactions.category_id, 
    isouter=True
).group_by(CategoriesTransactions.id).all()
```

La solución estuvo en priozar el `group_by` con la tabla de `CategoriesTransactions.id` en vez de `Transactions.category_id`